# How do I populate data pertaining to a specific item clicked on in a table?

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I have a table that shows all the items available in a database. What I am trying to do is get the data for a specific item in the same table row as a button when it is clicked.

Each item has a unique ID, if that helps. I'm just stuck on trying to get that ID so that I can get the data connected to it.

```
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
                {
                    echo '<tr id="itemRow">
                            <td>' .
                                $row["itemID"] .
                            '</td><td>' .
                                $row["ownerUserID"] .
                            '</td><td id="itemName" name="itemName">' .
                                $row["name"] .
                            '</td><td>' .
                                $row["currentCost"] .
                            '</td><td>' .
                                $row["buyout"] .
                            '</td><td>' .
                                $row["highestBidderID"] .
                            '</td><td style="padding-left: 2em; padding-right: 2em;">'  .
                                $row["Image"] .
                            '</td><td>
                                <button id="btnbid" name="btnbid" onclick="increaseBid()"> Place Bid </button>
                            </td><td>
                                <button id="btnbuyout" name="btnbuyout" onclick="buyoutItem()"> Buyout Item </button>
                            </td>
                          </tr>';
                }
                echo "</table>";
                mysqli_close();

            ?>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                function increaseBid()
                {
                    $("[name='itemName']").on('click', function() {
                        $("#browsecontent").html($(this)).val());
                    });
                }

                function buyoutItem()
                {
                    alert("Buying Item!");
                }            
        </script>
        </span>
```

That code is what I have for the values of the table rows and javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the snippest below, i make a rough example of how getting the item id, when you click on his row. 
Depending of what you want to achieve you may want to modify the click event.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
//event listener click on a row
  $("tbody tr").click(function() {
    // getting the first td referring to the id item and getting its text value
    let id = $(this).children('td').first().text();
    console.log(id);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> ID 1</td>
      <td>Item 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> ID 2</td>
      <td>Item 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ID 3</td>
      <td>Item 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```